# How to get all the volume path on a physicaldrive?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I need to  get all volume paths on a physicaldrive to dismount them. For example, if "\\.\PhysicalDrive1" includes partitions "G" and "I" etc., I need the strings "\\.\G:" and "\\.\I:". After enumerating the partitions on the drive, I will issue an [FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME control code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364562.aspx) on all of them.

Comment: Be aware that there may be partitions on the drive that don't have a drive letter.

Comment: If the drive don't have a drive letter, how can I how it exsist and then open it for dismount? @Harry Johnston

Comment: I'm not sure.  This example might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc542456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `GetLogicalDrives` to get a bitmask of logical drives in the system, then for each drive use `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` to find to find out which physical drives the logical drive resides on (remember that a logical drive can potentially be split across multiple physical drives).

Comment: Thanks. So I need to do a loop for logical drive "A" to "Z". I konow how to do that. But how about the logical drive that split across multiple physical drives? Which physical drive it belongs to?@Jonathan Potter